# Represent json file with a set of different data members to a C++ class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns

I want to parse a json file, where some elements are common each time while others are different based on a type. 
For example a message json:

```
{
    "title": string,
    "body": string,
    "type": int (0 for email, 1 for sms, 2 for terminal)
    "typeProperties": {
        // Different based on type value
    }
}
```

Shall I use inheritance to represent the json to C++ ? Shall I use a factory method to instantiate each time the appropriate class? Is there any other recommended approach for this?

```
class Message {
public:
   std::string title;
   std::string body;
   int type; // 0 - Email, 1 - SMS, 2 - Terminal
};

class Email : public Message {
public:
  std::vector<std::string> emailRecipients;
  std::vector<std::string> emailCC;
};

class Sms : public Message {
public:
  std::string  phoneNumber; 
};

class Terminal : public Message {
public:
  int terminalId;
};
```

Can I use a container of base class objects and somehow access the specific data members based on the type?

```
std::vector<Message> messages;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variant (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html)

or keep track of the type manually by setting the type integer. you can then declare `std::vector<Message*> messages;` (a vector of poiters to the base class) and `dynamic_cast` them to the appropriate type based on the value of `Message::type`

Comment: @IBeldus: I will accept your answer since there are two approaches. The variant approach seems to apply only when "typeProperties" doesn't contain another json object.